# Worst-case bound for quantile

Tags: probability, optimization, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X \in [a,b]$, known mean $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$ and known variance $\text{var}[X] = \sigma^2$. We are interested in an expression for the worst-case quantile. That is, for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ we wish to find $R$ such that
$$\begin{equation}\label{eq: 1}
\sup_{\mathbb{P} \in \mathcal{P}} \mathbb{P} [X < R] = \epsilon,
\end{equation}$$
where 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P} = \big\{\mathbb{P} : \text{supp}(X) \in [a,b],~\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X] = \mu,~\text{var}[X] = \sigma^2 \big\},
\end{equation}
is the set of all possible distribution functions. I have tried an approach using the Markov inequality below. However, I tend to find values of $R$ that are outside of $[a,b]$. Is there a mistake in my reasoning below?  In particular, it does not use the lower bound $a$. Or is there a better approach?

The Markov inequality states for a nonnegative random variable $Y$ and a constant $R>0$ that $\mathbb{P}[Y \geq R] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y]}{R}$. It is easily derived that for a random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{P}[X \leq b] = 1$ and a constant $R \leq \mathbb{E}[X]$ we have $\mathbb{P}[X\leq R] = \frac{b-\mathbb{E}[X]}{b-R}$ (use the Markov inequality for a random variable $\hat{X} = b-X$). Also, the Markov inequality can be shown to be tight. Therefore, we obtain
\begin{align}
\sup_{\mathbb{P} \in \mathcal{P}} \mathbb{P} [X < R] = \frac{b-\mu}{b-R},
\end{align}
and combining this with the first equation gives $R = \frac{\mu}{\epsilon} - \frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}b$. However, this implies that we only have $R \geq a$ if $\epsilon \geq \frac{b-\mu}{b-a}$. For example, with $[a,\mu,b] = \big[\frac{1}{20},\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{4}\big]$, this gives $\epsilon = 0.75$. For such a bound to be useful, we wish to have that $R \in[a,b]$ for all values of $\epsilon$.

Comment: To ignore $a$, just subtract it from $a,b,\mu$, then do your optimisation and finally add it back to the non-negative $R$ you calculate

Comment: Your example of $[a,\mu,b] = \big[\frac{1}{20},\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{4}\big]$ seems to ignore $\sigma^2$.  Is this deliberate? It could make the question much easier

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ignoring the $a$ does not seem to help, because the expression for $R$ turns out to be the same but with a term $-a$. The Markov bound does not use the $\sigma^2$, hence I didn't specify it in the example. I also tried including this via $X = \mu + \sigma^2 Z$, with $E(Z)=0$ and $\text{var}(Z) = 1$, but this also gives the same expression for $R$. If there is a way to obtain the expression without using the variance information I'd also be interested.

Comment: See the material at http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prob_bnds.html . This will allow you to incorporate the lower support bound $a$ into bounding probability calculations. So you can numerically calculate an upper bound for $P(a \le X \le R)$ for particular numerical values of $a, R, \mu, \sigma^2$ via numerical optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Mark! Their methods can be used to obtain a tight upper bound for the case with known expectation and variance, by setting their set C to not include any quadratic constraints, but only a bound $X\in C=[a,R]$. However, they do not take into account the support information, so for the case with support information their bound will not be tight (and hence we do not have the supremum).

Comment: @Stefan94 I believe the key to getting a tight constraint is to get a tight finite-dimensional (computable) formulation of the infinite dimensional constraints which do account for the support information. I left the details to you - hence I provided only a comment, not an answer.